# Word used to describe pointing out how someone is less than someone

Tags: word-request

What would you call a statement aimed at pointing out how someone else is less than someone else, perhaps even in an attempt to squabble the other person.

I don't know whether a precise word for this exists in the English language.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a word for this in your native language? What is that word? Have you tried using a bilingual dictionary?

Comment: Perhaps such a statement is [**belittling**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/belittle) in an attempt to [**provoke**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/provoke) them, but I don't know if there is a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sentences:

> You are **so much more of a** manager than I am.
>
> I am **so much less of** a manager than you are.

It means someone is a much better manager than I am, I don't make a very good manager.

Apparently, it's not one word to describe someone who is **superior** or **inferior** to someone else, but the phrases might do the job anyway. If they don't, please be more specific about the situation in which you want to use the word you are looking for.